# pandas to_sql raises error 'Identifier name is too long'

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, identifier

I am running python 2.7 with the Anaconda package manager. 
The **pandas.to_sql** command raises an **Identifier is too long** error.

The line of code where the error is raised:

```
def write_to_sql(self, pdata):

    pdata.to_sql(self._tblname, self._db.get_connection(), flavor = 'mysql', 
        if_exists='replace', index = True, index_label = [COLUMN_ALLIANCERANK, COLUMN_ALLIANCEID, 
COLUMN_ALLIANCENAME, COLUMN_PLAYERID, COLUMN_NICK, COLUMN_LASTUPDATED])
```

the input dataframe *pdata* is in the following format. all except the last numerical field (101, 102...) are indexes in the dataframe.

```
COLUMN_ALLIANCERANK    ...    COLUMN_LASTUPDATED  
value a1                ...    value x1               101
value a2                ...    value x2               102
```

Below is the error dump (only relevant portion)

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
... ...
  File "D:\Workspace\python\lnk\datasourceActivityTrackerChange.py", line 92, in write_to_sql
    COLUMN_ALLIANCENAME, COLUMN_PLAYERID, COLUMN_NICK, COLUMN_LASTUPDATED])  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1003, in to_sql
    dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 569, in to_sql
    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1633, in to_sql
    table.create()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 690, in create
    self._execute_create()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1400, in _execute_create
    conn.execute(stmt)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1059, "Identifier name 'ix_tbl_us3_activity_tracker_allianceRank_allianceId_allianceName_playerID_nick_lastUpdated' is too
long")
```

Looking up on the internet forums, it seems like mysql restricts identifiers to be 64 characters or less. So I have been using `if_exists = 'append'` instead of `'replace'` and creating the table directly in mysql, reducing table name and/or primary/foreign keys in the to_sql arguments, essentially anything to circumvent the error. But that has severely limited my flexibility as well as more messier (storing portion of the data in JSON files to avoid these errors) than it should be.

My question is
1. is there an alternative way where I can use `if_exists = 'replace'` but not be restricted to use short table/column names in order to fit into the <64 character requirement for mysql identifiers?
2. If there is a better way to achieve this, please share.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the source code in `.../site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py`, which is used for `create index ...` on the MySQL side:

```
ix_cols = [cname for cname, _, is_index in column_names_and_types
           if is_index]
if len(ix_cols):
    cnames = "_".join(ix_cols)
    cnames_br = ",".join([escape(c) for c in ix_cols])
    create_stmts.append(
        "CREATE INDEX " + escape("ix_" + self.name + "_" + cnames) +
        "ON " + escape(self.name) + " (" + cnames_br + ")")
```

IMO you will have either to create your index yourself in MySQL or to make sure that the index name is not longer than 64 characters.

Comment: Thanks Max. That's a good thought. I will use that file code to create my own. have you ever tried it before? if not with mysql, maybe something else, where you took a python library code and created a custom version for yourself?  
I have only done it once with a plot.ly source file, and I wonder if there are any tips/dos/donts for customizing a python source file (i will make a local copy for mine of course and not touch the original)